# Apache rewrite ignore images for processing permissions in PHP

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am noob to REGEX and have the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And the content of download.php file is

```
require_once ('users.php'); // user session 

$allowedExtensions = array(
    '.jpg',
    '.png',
    '.gif',
    '.ico',
);

$extension = substr($_GET['file'], -4);

// Requested file is not in allowed extension and is not a logged in user
If (!in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions) && !is_user()) {
    echo '<h1>Sorry, only members can download the files.</h1>';
    exit();
}
```

It works great and what it does is:

1. Triggers verification whenever the files in "uploads" directory is served by Apache, specially for direct links.
2. If it's a member (logged in user) serve all the files
3. If it's not a member, only allow images, but deny access to any other files

But I think there is too much overhead in the download.php script to verify for image extenions each and every time, so I am trying to ignore the images directly from .htaccess rewrite rule. Looks like I have to change the following code

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to skip the images before passing to download.php, but don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition that excludes those extensions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ download.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```